# Remove User Input From Seekbar

Tags: android

I would like the ability to remove the ability for a user to interact with the SeekBar, from within the activity.

### The scenario:

User slide's the Seekbar once.... then onStopTrackingTouch: further user interaction with the seekbar is denied....
then Button OnClick... User interaction with Seekbar restored..

---

I cant find an attribute for the seekbar that will allow this...?

One possible solution i have considered, is overlaying an image view containing a clear image. But this does not stop the underlying SeekBar from taking user touch input..?

Answer (score 2):

SeekBar descends from the View class so why not disable it?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setEnabled(boolean)